# How to position <a href > element by using CSS class?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, tags

I want o position a link at required place .The problem is that it is positioning margin left but not margin top. I don't know what is missing.

```css
.LearnMoreTxt{
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 730px;
    color: rgb(0, 140, 255);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="LearnMoreTxt">Learn More ></a>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! did you tried removing `margin-left`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Sandy please make your anchor (a) tag block element using `display: block;` in your style declaration. By default anchor (a) tags get rendered as inline elements.

```css
.LearnMoreTxt {
    margin-top: 100px; /* change default value */
    margin-left: 100px; /* change default value */
    color: rgb(0, 140, 255);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="LearnMoreTxt"> Learn More > </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to apply `display: block;` and `white-space: nowrap;` this is because of your `<a>` text does not break in two lines.

```css
.LearnMoreTxt{
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 730px;
    color: rgb(0, 140, 255);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="LearnMoreTxt">Learn More ></a>
```

Comment: I got it! Thank for answer!